# Redirect from subdomain to main domain using code on the main domain

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am looking for a way to redirect site "B" to site "A" from "A". The subdomain are in the clients account however they are just parked. I have been tasked to find a way that I can implement some sort of code on site "A" that will allow site "B" to be redirected. I am not even sure that you can redirect a sub to the main from the main.

I've implemented

```
if (window.location.href != "https://www.websiteb.com") {
    window.location = "https://www.websitea.com";
}
```

but it creates an endless loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This would of course be an endless loop--your code is if you are NOT on site B, redirect to site A.  Well, site A is NOT site B, so it would redirect to site A continuously until Site A somehow magically became site B.

Comment: Hi RockinRichard, if you feel your question has been answered, please don't forget to mark one of the answers as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate so we can further help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to remotely define the forward from b to a? (Because that - to my knowledge - is not possible using JavaScript.)

The problem with your code is that site a redirects the browser over and over to itself (when not on site B -> redirect to A is what it says).

Comment: yeah I kind of figured. What language would this be possible with if any? We have learned we can't do it server side because of our setup.

Comment: Then you are pretty much helpless, unless you are allowed to put code on the parked subdomains. In that case you could just put the JavaScript Code on there and exchange the "!=" with a "===".

Answer (score 0):

In short, **there is no way to redirect a user away from a domain that you do not have a web server running on**, so you will not be able to redirect users from Website B to Website A using code running only on Website A. You need to be able to serve code from Website B in order to be able to redirect the user from Website B to Website A.

If you are able to serve code on Website B, (since you said you can't do any thing server-side, we will use JS instead of a 301 redirect) you can do the following in JavaScript:

```
window.location.replace('https://www.websitea.com')
```

By using `location.replace` instead of just setting the location, you don't pollute the browser's history at all, and the back button will work properly for your users. This will only work if you serve the page with this redirect code **on Website B**. With this setup, you don't need any special code on Website A.